# How to create a context menu in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, contextmenu

I want to create a context menu using C# that will display next to the node similar to what happens here in Visual Studio:

[image]

The code I have now causes the main form to flicker.

```
private void treeView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        var myForm = new Form {Text = "My Form"};
        myForm.SetBounds(10, 10, 200, 200);

        myForm.Show();
        // Determine if the form is modal.
        if (myForm.Modal == false)
        {
            // Change borderstyle and make it not a top level window.
            myForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            myForm.TopLevel = false;
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: What you show in VS isn't modal, it's a context menu.  Which are you looking for?

Comment: Well probably context menu then

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why not simply use `Form.ShowDialog`?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx):

**Form.ShowDialog Method**

> Shows the form as a modal dialog box.

Comment: Cannot access non-static method ShowDailog in static context, exception

Comment: @atbyrd, in your code snippet, what you should do is call `myForm.ShowDialog()`. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

You should set up `treeView1.ContextMenu` instead of the approach you're taking.

Answer (score 0):

You should read and try `ContextMenu` control of c#. I think it will resolve your problem rather than the technique you used..... Or other than use, `myform.showdialog();` with `setbounds()` methods.